# Why pygame use the base font instead of the custom I want?

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I tried to use a custom font found in an Assets/Fonts/ file in relation to my code with this :

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Assets\Fonts\alagard.ttf", 18)
```

and then after to display my text :

```
 texte = font.render("blabla",True,(255, 255, 255))
 screen.blit(texte, (x, y))
```

The text is displayed but the font used is the base font and not the custom font I want.
I don't understand what I do wrong because no error is displayed in the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use `pygame.font.Font()` instead of `pygame.font.SysFont()`.